# Search Map in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am changing my app to use fragments and I'm having an issue searching my map markers in my fragment. When it was an activity, I did this:

```
search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            String searchText = search.getText().toString();

            // hide the virtual keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 
                                      InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);

            handled = true;

            boolean found = false;

            for(Marker m : list) {

                if(m.getTitle().contains(searchText)){
                    m.showInfoWindow();
                    found = true;
                    break;
                } else if(m.getSnippet().contains(searchText)) {
                    m.showInfoWindow();
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(found == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Matches Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        return handled;
    }
});
```

When I use this in my fragment, "Found" is always false. What do I need to change to make this work in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel dumb. I forgot to actually add each marker to my array.